# SharePoint 2013 in place search issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am doing an in place search in a document library and results are being returned just fine.  However, some users are reporting seeing the following message:

Some files might be hidden. Include these in your search

I also receive this message at random times for different searches.  There seems to be reports of this on various boards with no real answer.  Anyone know why this message would occur?

Answer (score 0):

This may relate to the Search Service Settings > Content Source in Central Admin. Ensure that the addressers are correct and that the crawl have the same entry as you do. Normally you want to point the url to the default zone.

When done, reset the index and start a new full crawl.

Comment: Yes, I had checked the URL.  Everyone can see results using global search, so I dont think this is an issue with the crawl.